# Create dataframe with hierarchical indices and extra columns from non-hierarchically indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

Consider a simple dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5,2))
print(x)
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

I would like to create a hierarchically indexed dataframe of the form:

```
     0         1
     a    b    a    b
0    0  NaN    1  NaN
1    2  NaN    3  NaN
2    4  NaN    5  NaN
3    6  NaN    7  NaN
4    8  NaN    9  NaN
```

where the 'a' columns correspond to the original dataframe columns and the 'b' columns are blank (or nan).
I can certainly create a hierarchically indexed dataframe with all NaNs and loop over the columns of the original dataframe, writing them into
the new dataframe.  Is there something more compact than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

```
extra_level = ['a', 'b']
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x.columns, extra_level])
x.columns = new_cols[::len(x.columns)] # select all the first element of extra_level
x = x.reindex(columns=new_cols)
print(x)
   0      1    
   a   b  a   b
0  0 NaN  1 NaN
1  2 NaN  3 NaN
2  4 NaN  5 NaN
3  6 NaN  7 NaN
4  8 NaN  9 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Very much like @Ben.T I am using MultiIndex.from_product:

```
x.assign(l='a')
 .set_index('l', append=True)
 .unstack()
 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x.columns.tolist(), ['a','b']]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   0      1    
   a   b  a   b
0  0 NaN  1 NaN
1  2 NaN  3 NaN
2  4 NaN  5 NaN
3  6 NaN  7 NaN
4  8 NaN  9 NaN
```

Comment: Nice trick to add a column with the value first :)

Comment: haha a pea brain that worth 114K rep, I want the same :D